# Why i can't count the "o_jumlah_harga", i'm put the "o_jumlah_harga" as array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sorry for bad question or something wrong with me ._.
here, i'm newbie and now learning python 3.5!

I am stuck on this problem a.k.a "a r r a y".
can some one help me for the problem ?

The error is

```
o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong) * int(2500))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not  'list'
```

The code is

```
input_banyak_jenis = int(input("Masukan Banyak Jenis yang ingin dibeli : "))
kode_potong=[]
banyak_potong=[]
o_tipe = []
o_harga = []
o_jumlah_harga =[]
i = 0
while i <= input_banyak_jenis:
    print("Jenis Ke - ", i)
    kode_potong.append(input("Kode Potong D/P/S : "))
    banyak_potong.append(int(input("Banyak Potong : ")))
    if kode_potong[i] == "D" or kode_potong[i] =="d":
        o_tipe.append("Dada")
        o_harga.append(2500)
        o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong)*int(2500))
    elif kode_potong[i] == "P" or kode_potong[i] =="p":
        o_tipe.append("Paha")
        o_harga.append(2000)
        o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong)*int(2000))
    elif kode_potong[i] == "S" or kode_potong[i] == "s":
        o_tipe.append("Sayap")
        o_harga.append(1500)
        o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong)*int(1500))
    else:
        print("Harusnya anda memasukan yang ada di pilihan !!!!!")
        o_harga.append(0)
    i = i + 1

print("          Gerobak Fried Chicken           ")
print("------------------------------------------")
print("No.  Jenis     Harga     Banyak     Jumlah")
print("     Potong    Satuan    Potong     Harga ")
print("------------------------------------------")
a=0
while a<=input_banyak_jenis:
    print(o_tipe[a], o_harga[a], banyak_potong[a], o_jumlah_harga[a])
    a = a + 1

enter code here
```

Comment: First off: It's not an array. it's a list.

Comment: Well, the error is very explicit in this case. `banyak_potong` is a list and you're passing it to `int`.

Comment: You are trying to convert int list to int, Correct that code.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not that you can't count `o_jumlah_harga`. It's that you're trying to convert `banyak_potong` which is a list into a int in lines like:

```
o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong)*int(1500))
```

Take a look at this:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append('4')
>>> a.append('5')
>>> a.append('6')
>>> int(a)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

You need to give something with an index:

```
>>> int(a[1])
5
```

Comment: @Oncom Mark the reply as the answer if it answered your question

Comment: i d k how to mark, but my script has cange to this
o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong[i])*int(price))

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Work for me

you should added [i] in variable banyak_potong

```
o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong[i])*int(2500))
```

full code

```
input_banyak_jenis = int(input("Masukan Banyak Jenis yang ingin dibeli : "))
kode_potong=[]
banyak_potong=[]
o_tipe = []
o_harga = []
o_jumlah_harga =[]
i = 0
while i <= input_banyak_jenis:
    print("Jenis Ke - ", i)
    kode_potong.append(input("Kode Potong D/P/S : "))
    banyak_potong.append(int(input("Banyak Potong : ")))
    if kode_potong[i] == "D" or kode_potong[i] =="d":
        o_tipe.append("Dada")
        o_harga.append(2500)
        o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong[i])*int(2500))
    elif kode_potong[i] == "P" or kode_potong[i] =="p":
        o_tipe.append("Paha")
        o_harga.append(2000)
        o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong[i])*int(2000))
    elif kode_potong[i] == "S" or kode_potong[i] == "s":
        o_tipe.append("Sayap")
        o_harga.append(1500)
        o_jumlah_harga.append(int(banyak_potong[i])*int(1500))
    else:
        print("Harusnya anda memasukan yang ada di pilihan !!!!!")
        o_harga.append(0)
    i = i + 1

print("          Gerobak Fried Chicken           ")
print("------------------------------------------")
print("No.  Jenis     Harga     Banyak     Jumlah")
print("     Potong    Satuan    Potong     Harga ")
print("------------------------------------------")
a=0
while a<=input_banyak_jenis:
    print(o_tipe[a], o_harga[a], banyak_potong[a], o_jumlah_harga[a])
    a = a + 1
```